# Can/Should I fix an opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

My question was marked as opinion-based:
[Should Equatable include the id for Identifiable structs in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646838/should-equatable-include-the-id-for-identifiable-structs-in-swiftui/77652058#77652058)

I am reaching out, because I am unsure on how to proceed in way that benefits this community best. To be honest, I was a bit surprised about the discussion this question sparked. In its context I clearly misinterpreted a piece of documentation, which unfortunately side-tracked the actual question. But maybe the nature of "Should I do X in SwiftUI?" is already wrong.

So what can I do best?

- Delete the question.
- Keep the question in the closed state.
- Rewrite the question.

Comment: Normally I'd say leave it closed and let [the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) take care of it, but in this case you wrote it. If you think you can fix it, fix it. No point to having a poorly received deleted question hanging around and threating you with a question ban.

Comment: I can't help with this question per se since I am ignorant in the ways of Swift, but note that I did place a comment at the bottom of the original question, in order to notify anyone who reviews the comment that this meta issue is being discussed. You may wish to comment to individuals in the comment thread if you desire any of their input in this.

Comment: You should always fix a question, over allowing it to be deleted (or deleting it yourself), if you believe you can fix it and reopen it. Now if the question was caused by a typo, I would argue no amount of edits can result in that question being reopened.

Comment: Start by cleaning up the comments.

Comment: If "fixing" is "rewriting", you might as well delete and start over. **If** you want to post a new question.

Comment: @Sweeper do you see merit in rewriting this question? (as a side-note your comments *did* help me get a better understanding of the Equatable protocol)

Comment: Essentially as soon as you start something with the word "Should" and especially the words "Should I", alarms should already be going off in your head. Even if it isn't intended opinionated, it is going to read as such. People judge what they see, not what they have to read between the lines.

Comment: You cannot ping users who are not part of this comment thread. And again, if you want to _rewrite_ it, better delete it and post a new one.

Comment: @yivi, (and others) thanks for the suggestions. The last thing I want is waste people's time. I'm not certain I can 'fix' the question, so I will keep the question closed.

Comment: @JackGoossen - You had left a comment or statement suggesting the entire problem was caused by what was essentially a typo. You can’t fix questions like that.

Comment: @SecurityHound, that’s not what I meant. I made an error (misinterpreting documentation) in the context of describing the question. I don’t think that in itself rendered the question invalid. But that also doesn’t mean it is a good question for stackoverflow. I’ll think it through, but will probably delete the question within a couple of days.